# Problem with socket connection in flutter and nginx server

Tags: node.js, flutter, express, socket.io

I'm having difficulty making a websocket connection.

I'm using flutter web as an application, node for the api, socker.io, nginx

I'm getting this error:
websocket_transport.dart:110 WebSocket connection to 'wss://myapi/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

**This is one of the connections in my flutter application**

```
@override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  connectToServer();
}

void connectToServer() async {
Map<String, dynamic> getUser = await controller.getToken();

userRoles.add(UserModel.fromJson(getUser));
idEmpresa = userRoles[0].idEmpresa!;

IO.Socket socket = IO.io(
  ApiRota.baseApiSocket,
  IO.OptionBuilder()
      .setPath('/socket.io/')
      .setTransports(['websocket']).build(),
);

socket.onConnect((_) {
  socket.emit('request_company_dashboard', {idEmpresa});
});
socket.on('request_company_dashboard', (dashboard) {
  setState(() {
    dashboardCompany = DashboardCommpanyModel.fromJson(dashboard);
  });
});
socket.onDisconnect((_) => print('disconnect'));
     }
```

**this is the basis of my api:**

```
      const app = express();

         app.use(express.json());

   app.use(
     cors({
    origin: "*",
   })
 );

  const http = require("http").createServer(app); 

    const io = require("socket.io")(http, {
      path: "/socket.io/",
     cors: {
     origin: "*", 
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        },
      });


       io.on("connection", (socket) => {
         console.log("client conectado");
        socket.on("request_company_dashboard", async (data) => {
           getCompanyDashboardSocket(socket, data);
        });

        });

         mongoose
          .connect(process.env.URL_DB, {
           })
           .then(() => {
             const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000; 
          http.listen(PORT, () => {
          console.log(`Listen ${PORT}`);
            });
         })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

**this is my nginx server:**

server {

```
root /var/www/api_rede_neutra;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html app.js;

server_name myapi  www.myapi;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

}

location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
}

listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapi/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapi/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

 }
 server {
if ($host = myapi) {
 return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

  server_name myapi  www.myapi;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot


  }
```

for additional information, in my test environment on localhost it works perfectly, my api and my flutter web project are on different servers, I'm using pm2, mongo, express, socket.io, nginx. flutter, mongo

Please help me, I've been on this task for more than 6 days, the boss is already demanding and I don't have a senior to help me.